# this.setState is not a function, react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I am aware there are similar issues but none of them helped me to fix mine.

So here is my issue.

I am working with react native and using the flux dispatcher. Dispatch and register of my app dispatcher works fine. My issue is that when I want to change/set the state inside the dispatch register function I always get the error message that this.setState() is not a function. Of course I thought this must be a binding issue then (writing in es6), so I tried all sorts of binding "this" but I still can't get it work. Has anyone any idea why?

Here is that bit of code that doesn't work:

```
testDispatcher() {    
    AppDispatcher.register( (action) => {
        if ( action.action === TEST_ACTION ) {
            // I tried setting state inside here
            this.setState({
                view: action.view
            }).bind(this); // with or without this bind doesn't make a difference

            // I also tried having a function outside of this function where I set the state.. this doesn't work either.
            //this.updateView('home').bind(this);
            console.log('dispatch register');
        }
    });
}
```

I also tried to console log "this" inside my register function and "this" does return my app class.

Answer (score 4):

The `=>` binds `this` to the scope of `testDispatcher()`. That's probably not what you want. In this case I think you should drop the `=>` notation but simply a regular anonymous function.

Also, `this.setState(...args...).bind(this)` is totally wrong. 1) The `this.` part indicates that the `.bind(this)` is redundant. 2) The syntax for binding is like: `foo.setState.bind(notFoo, ...args...)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But wouldn't I want to bind this to my AppDispatcher function inside my testDispatcher function? If I don't do that I end up having the object of the dispatcher in there and then I can't use this.setState as well. It is really odd as when I use the arrow function and I log "this" I do get get my Class and that is what I would want, but it still wouldn't let me use this.setState.

Comment: I solved it! I didn't extend from React Component inside my class, therefore setState wasn't a function.. oh boy.. sorry, I should have posted more code then this would have been more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

My class didn't extend from React Component, therefore this.setState was not a function.

Comment: ran into the same problem. Your answer made sense!

Comment: like this? export default class MyWeatherApp extends Component